# Cannot select the last element with class name : JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-selectors

In my webpage I have divs with same class name `message_box vlistngbox item`. I am calling an ajax function in the scroll event of page and I want to append the response after the last div with class `message_box vlistngbox item`.

I tried with,

```
$("#masnrycontainer .message_box vlistngbox item:last").after(response);
```

But it is not getting appended as it failed to choose the last div with class name `message_box vlistngbox item`. Can anyone help me to select the last div ?

I am sharing the part of my HTML code below:

```
<div class="main_content_wrapper">
    <div class="mainpading">
        <div class="mainwraper main_msnry">
            <div class="left_wrapper">
                <div class="inside_left_wrapper">
                      <div class="user_accountlinks">
                                <!-- I have menus in my page here -->
                       </div>
                        <div class="useracntmenuresponsive"><i class=" ico_color2 fa fa-list"></i></div>
                    <!-- for Responsive Menu Ends -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main_content_wraper">
                <div class="inside_mainconatinerwrap">
                    <div class="msnry" id="masnrycontainer">
                        <div class="message_box vlistngbox item">
                                   <!-- Content -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="message_box vlistngbox item">
                                <!-- Content -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="message_box vlistngbox item">
                                <!-- Content -->
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
           </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple classes in same element.selector for last item would be `.message_box.vlistngbox.item:last`.You need to use:

```
$("#masnrycontainer .message_box.vlistngbox.item:last").after(response);
```

Comment: @Jenz: indeed it should :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed `.` before `item` and `vlistngbox`  for class selector. Also remove remove the `space` between these classes to select element with all these classes.

```
$("#masnrycontainer .message_box.vlistngbox.item:last").after(response);
```

Comment: This `.message_box vlistngbox` wont work. both classes exists in same element

Comment: Thanks @MilindAnantwar, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

use [last](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('.message_box').last().html();
```

this will select last div html ....you can do any thing with this div now